# flexbox with max-height in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I'm trying to find a way to make my flexbox work correctly in IE10:

Here is an example which should work in Chrome, Firefox, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/vN65r/

I have an absolute-positioned flexbox which has a fixed header, fixed footer, and fill body. The flexbox will take up as much height as it needs, but if it reaches the maximum height then the body will begin to scroll. So far, so good.

However, if you open the link in IE10, it doesn't work. The body now overflows rather than scrolling, causing the both the bottom of the list and the footer to be hidden. The cause seems to be the max-height CSS on .lhs:

```
max-height: 200px;
```

If this is changed to be just 'height':

```
height: 200px;
```

Then lo and behold, it works again. However it also stops the flexbox being variable height, so isn't a viable solution for me. Can anyone see how I can make this work in IE10, as well as the other flexbox-supportive browsers?

Comment: have you tried a simplier way : http://jsfiddle.net/vN65r/4/

Comment: That doesn't appear to work in IE10 either

Answer (score 1):

the solution i see would be to set your `max-height` to your middle container . you may use `calc()` http://jsfiddle.net/vN65r/5/ example with a minimal CSS

```
.flex-container-v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:200px;
    background:gray;
}
.flex-fill {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: 10px;   
    max-height:calc(200px - 60px);
}
```

Comment: two test , one overflows, and the other is small enough http://jsfiddle.net/vN65r/6/

Comment: This certainly works, but it means I have to calculate the height of my 'fixed' elements which isn't straightforward since the contents of the container will be dynamic. That, and it seems to defeat the purpose of using a flexbox which is meant to handle this for you.

Comment: do not use calc() and set fair max-height to flex-fill. are headers and footers happen to lay on multiple lines ? IE10 & 11 do not work properly, you need  work around.

Comment: The header and footer could be varying heights. There may even be multiple 'fixed' elements, and a variable div. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/vN65r/ . I'm hoping to be able to just drop things into this panel and have it work without having to adjust styles.

Comment: For ie , you will need to set the max-height on the element you want to see scrolling, else , use javascript to retrieves heights and apply the adequat max-height (or heigh) to your scrolling element. You have to deal with that difference :) display:flex is a quiet new option for our browser , it needs to mature a bit more :) and still needs some fallback

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue on IE11 and managed to solve it without any *fixed* CSS values. I nested the vertical flexbox in a horizontal one, and used `max-height: inherit`:

```css
.flex-container-row { /* Added */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;  
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container-v {
  width: 100%; /* Added */
  max-height: inherit; /* Added */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-fill {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -moz-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.flex-fixed {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -moz-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.lhs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.list-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-row lhs">
<div class="flex-container-v">
    <header class="flex-fixed">Header</header>
    <div class="flex-fill list-container">
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <footer class="flex-fixed">Footer</footer>
</div>
</div>
```

Tested on Chrome 55, Firefox 47 and IE 11 (don't have IE10 to test)